# How do I assign a pointer variable to a different const?

Tags: c++, c

I have a menu pointer that I want to be able to change between 2 different char arrays. My goal is to be able to change the global menu and then be able to call it but i'm having trouble assigning the menu variable.

This is the error I'm getting:

> `cannot convert ‘const char* (*)[11]’ to ‘char*’ in initialization`

```
    const char *chapterSelect[] = {"Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", "Chapter 3", "Chapter 4", "Chapter 5", "Chapter 6", "Chapter 7", "Chapter 8", "Chapter 9", "Chapter 10", "Chapter 11"};
    const char *chapter1[] = {"Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9", "Level 10", "Level 11"};
    char* menu = &chapterSelect;
    drawMenuItems(menu);
    menu = &chapter1;
    drawMenuItems(menu);

void drawMenuItems(const char *Items[])
{}
```

Comment: `menu` should be a `const char**`.

Comment: Is this about C or C++? You tagged both. They are different languages and C++ has e.g. `std::string` which makes string handling a lot easier.

Comment: @tkausl Strictly even `const char**` would be the wrong type

Comment: Is it just luck that both "menus" have 11 elements? The needless repetition of "Chapter x" and "Level x" could be replaced by a a more capable function and less copy/paste coding.

Comment: If you want `menu` to store the address of a `const char *[]` (which decays to a `const char **`) then it will point to a `const char **`. A pointer to `const char **` is of type `const char ***`

Comment: This `void drawMenuItems(const char *Items[]) {}` seems to be the definition of `drawMenuItems`. From this it's clear what type the function expects. So why pass it a `char*`?

Comment: @Friedrich The posted code and question is valid for both C and C++. This is not changed by the fact that C++ may offer a different way to accomplish something similar. I know it is in fashion on SO to say "C and C++ are different languages", but they have a large common core and it is not uncommon to mix C and C++ in the same application. In some situations a solution may even be required to be valid in both languages. Tagging both C and C++ is IMHO not "automatically" wrong.

Comment: Also.... you tagged with both C and C++. While a C++ compiler handles most pure C code jist like a C compiler would, there are differences so **do not consider C++ the same as C**. Further, if you really mean C++, you would not write code like this (unless you were forced to it due to interfacing to 3rd party code with C like interface).

Comment: @nielsen a language is more than vocabulary and grammar (i.e. syntax) there's idioms and all that. In that respect, there's a world of difference between C and C++. Sure, a C++ compiler will swallow a lot of C but that does not make it the gold standard. It would be poor advice to tell someone how to accomplish something in C++ the C way and vice versa.

Comment: @nielsen "C and C++ are different languages" Because they _are_ different languages. `char**` would be a valid type to point at the first item of an array of pointers pointing at string literals _in C_ but it is wrong _in C++_. Because the languages treat string literals (and character literals) different and it is highly relevant to this question. So it's not just as simple as C++ best practices recommend std::string.

Answer (score 2):

- Problem 1: Your use of `const` is inconsistent.
- Problem 2: To point at the first item of an array of pointers to char, you need to use (const) `char**`.
- Problem 3: `&chapterSelect` doesn't make any sense since it gives a pointer to the type of the array, not of the first element.

Solution:

```
const char** menu = chapterSelect;
```

Or equivalent:

```
const char** menu = &chapterSelect[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `&chapterSelect` is `const char* (*)[11]` and since there is no implicit conversion from `const char* (*)[11]` to a `char*`, we get the mentioned error. Basically, there is a type mismatch on the left and right side.

To solve this you can make sure that the type on the lhs and rhs are same:

```
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------->changed type to this
void drawMenuItems(const char*(*Item)[11])
{ 
}
int main()
{
    const char *chapterSelect[] = {"Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", "Chapter 3", "Chapter 4", "Chapter 5", "Chapter 6", "Chapter 7", "Chapter 8", "Chapter 9", "Chapter 10", "Chapter 11"};
    const char *chapter1[] = {"Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9", "Level 10", "Level 11"};
//--vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------->changed type to this 
    const char*(*menu)[11] = &chapterSelect;
    drawMenuItems(menu); //or drawMenuItems(&chapterSelect);
    menu = &chapter1;
    drawMenuItems(menu); // or drawMenuItems(&chapter1);
}
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aGbjEeEnd)

---

##### C++20

Note that with C++20 we're allowed to do this for array of different sizes. This means that you can change `menu`'s declaration to:

```
//---------------------v---------------------->works with C++20, NO SIZE GIVEN HERE!!
    const char*(*menu)[] = &chapterSelect;
```

[c++ 20 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dW3jP4Yax)

Comment: what if I added more chapters char arrays that aren't all size 11?

Comment: While this seems correct, I think the more simple solution is to avoid the `menu` variable and just call the function directly like: `drawMenuItems(chapterSelect);` But okay... it depends on what `drawMenuItems` is supposed to do...

Comment: @SupportUkraine Added that in the updated answer as comment. Also note it should be `drawMenuItems(&chapterSelect);` instead of `drawMenuItems(chapterSelect);`

Comment: @JasonLiam With the definition of `drawMenuItems` **in OPs code**, it's as simple as `drawMenuItems(chapterSelect);`

Comment: @SupportUkraine Ah, i see.

Comment: @user2570937 With C++20 you can omit the size `11` of the array. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dW3jP4Yax). Note the comment in the above [linked demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dW3jP4Yax) which shows that my solution will work for different size also.

Comment: The common solution can be made flexible if e.g. `chapterSelect` is made a module static variable such that the constant `11` can be replaced by the compile-time calculated size `sizeof(chapterSelect)/sizeof(chapterSelect[0])`.

Answer (score -2):

I will start with answering your question but will follow with additional suggestion:

The error you see is because you are taking an address of `const char*` which in practice means the returned value should be `const char**`.

Instead of:

```
char* menu = &chapterSelect;
```

use:

```
char** menu = (char**) &chapterSelect;
```

Note there are 2 points of change. One for menu type and one for explicit const-cast-away.

Although the above will solve the compilation error - I want to raise a few suggestions:

1. I don't understand the need for `char** menu` as you can pass the arrays' addresses directly to `drawMenuItems()`. If the function that from its name means it prints the array as menu - then it shouldn't alter the array and should receive a `const char**`.
2. It is not good practice to cast-away const. The compiler is considering you did a coding mistake and the right side const-cast-away is telling both compiler and other developers that you are casting-away-const on purpose.
3. When your code includes a call to a function (`drawMenuItems()`), it is good to provide at least the function declaration for clearer understanding of the readers.

I hope this resolves the issue raised.

Comment: This is not correct. The code does not (quote) "taking and address of const char*". It takes the address of an array of const char*. That's a completely different thing.

Comment: @SupportUkraine you are right - I have edited my answer.

Comment: "It is not good practice to cast-away const." Not only that but it invokes undefined behavior. The solution here is to fix the actual bug - no const qualifier for the `menu` variable. However, `const char** menu = &chapterSelect` is still wrong and invalid C and invalid C++ because those two types are not compatible. Rule of thumb: beginners should pretty much _never_ use casts for any purpose.